Find k so that $f(x)=x^2$ if $x \le 2$ and $f(x)=k-x^2$ if $x \gt 2$ is a continuous function.
The problem:
Find k so that $f(x)=x^2$ if $x \le 2$ and $f(x)=k-x^2$ if $x \gt 2$ is a continuous function.
The solution:
$k=8$
What I have tried:
The point where $f(x) = x^2$ ends and $f(x)=k-x^2$ starts is (2, 4) since $x=2$ gives us $f(x)=4$ when plugged inside $f(x)=x^2$. As $f(x)=k-x^2$ starts past the point $(2, 4)$ I find out $k$ in this following way:
$f(x)=k-x^2 \Rightarrow 4 = k-2^2 \iff k=4+4=8$
My question:
While I do reach the right solution I have a feeling my chosen method is not the correct way to think. I’m almost viewing the point $(2, 4)$ as a point of intersection which feels wrong for whatever reason. Am I thinking right going about solving this problem like I have?

What you have done is correct.

You are right, in the sense that, you are looking both right and left limits
For your piecewise function $f$, $x^2$ is continuous on the left of $x=2$ and $k-x^2$ is continuous on the right of $x=2$. The only problem is at end point, namely $x=2$. This is a point you looking for.  At that point, we have to calculate both left and right limits.
$\lim_{h \to 0}   f(2-h)=\lim_{h \to 0} (2-h)^2=4$
$\lim_{h \to 0}   f(2+h)=\lim_{h \to 0} [k-(2+h)^2]=\lim_{h \to 0} [k-4-4h-h^2]=k-4$
So if $k=8$, both limits coincide and we conclude our function is continuous.
